# upgrade from magento 2.2.5 to 2.3 error Front controller reached 100 router match iterations Issue

Tags: magento2.3

As I upgraded my magento from 2.2.5 to 2.3 all works fine but when trying to access the website an iteration error appear saying:

> Front controller reached 100 router match iterations Issue.

After searching for solutions online and all fails except that someone say something about old cached data is corrupted, so I remove `var/cache` then clean and flush cache but the error still appears.

I solved the problem by disabling cache for configuration so the cache status now is like this:
Current status:

```
                        config: 0
                        layout: 1
                    block_html: 1
                   collections: 1
                    reflection: 1
                        db_ddl: 1
               compiled_config: 1
                           eav: 1
         customer_notification: 1
            config_integration: 1
        config_integration_api: 1
                     full_page: 1
             config_webservice: 1
                     translate: 1
                        vertex: 0
```

I think this is a temporary and not a professional solution, anyone may help me figure it out and solve the problem of config cache?

Comment: do u have any custom module installed in your magento?

Comment: yes I have in the app/code there is a module that i created

Comment: @EmadKarhely any solution of it.

Comment: @padhiyargaurang I downgrade it to 2.2.5 since the 2.3 still not stable till the post date. I didn't try it anymore you may see a stable version now I guess

Comment: @EmadKarhely Ok, Thanks